# How to fix Navigator not working in flutter bloc pattern?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am trying to make an application using Pokemon api as an exercise.
I am trying to make it using the Bloc pattern.
If you click on GridTile, you need to get indexID and move to DetailPage.
Getting the IndexID is fine, but it doesn't go to the page.
I can't seem to build the page, but I don't know what the problem is.
It would be really appreciated if you could tell me what the problem is.

I put the code on github because it would be good to see the whole code.

https://github.com/Jun-Kor/pokedex.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is not your navigation, it's your Bloc, what happens is that when you enter the **PokemonDetailsView** page, with the **BlocBuilder<PokemonDetailsBloc, PokemonDetailsState>** it cannot find its provider (the one in the main) but, if we go directly there, you have it written, right ?

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: MultiBlocProvider( // here is the problem
        providers: [
          BlocProvider<PokemonBloc>(
              create: (context) =>
                  PokemonBloc()..add(const PokemonPageRequestEvent(page: 0))),
          BlocProvider<PokemonDetailsBloc>(
              create: (context) => PokemonDetailsBloc()),
        ],
        child: const PokedexView(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Well, the **MultiBlocProvider** has to be the main parent that is going to provide for the whole **MaterialApp**, not be a child of it, I mean ? That's why the problem was asking for a Bloc provider, but I
it couldn't find one.

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(  // change here
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<PokemonBloc>(
            create: (context) =>
                PokemonBloc()..add(const PokemonPageRequestEvent(page: 0))),
        BlocProvider<PokemonDetailsBloc>(
            create: (context) => PokemonDetailsBloc()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Material App',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.red,
        ),
        home: const PokedexView(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
But I tried your code and it gives the same result.

Comment: Do you have some error ?

Comment: ```
Reload already in progress, ignoring request
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building _BodyBuilder:
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<PokemonDetailsBloc> above this BlocBuilder<PokemonDetailsBloc, PokemonDetailsState> Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.

```

Comment: I fix the error, just wait to my edit

Comment: Wow. Your solution is perfect.
I finally solved the problem, and the code works fine.
I've been following an old project on YouTube and had to revamp all of my code.
The problem was that MultiBlocPovider was applied only to the PokedexView, not the entire page.
Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad you got it solved, sometimes Bloc is a bit fussy but I see you're handling it well, cheers!